Why is the Finder not counting some items for folder Get Info?
macOS Sonoma 14.5
In a couple of instances I've noticed so far, Finder's Get Info window's "Size:" line shows a significantly reduced number in "for [number] items". Using command-line tools, a text editor, and my own code, I can get (I believe) a true count of items, which I can verify by counting the items listed in Finder's main window when the folder at issue is opened.
For such folders, Finder accurately reports total bytes and space on disk as measured by other tools.
The clearest example I have is the folder ~/.cache/nvim/luac which contains 1,650 items while Finder reports:
Size: 7,919,797 bytes (11.8 MB on disk) for 0 items
A visual scan of the items indicates that they all have the extension .luac
I have just noticed this Finder behavior, so I don't know its age. Is it a bug or might there be a rationale for Finder not counting some items for its Get Info?

It's possible that Finder isn't recursively counting aliases/sym links.

@benwiggy Finder doesn't count symlinks. As to recursive: if the "end" of a chain of links is to a file within the purview of the directory on which Get Info is invoked, that file would, I think, be counted.

@benwiggy Correction: Finder does count symlinks.

...except it doesn't count links to within the directory containing the link.
